# Parse string in javascript using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have html fragment on my page and it looks like this:

```
...
    <address>
       6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A<br>
       Falls Church, VA 22041-2102
    </address>
...
```

How can I parse this string using jQuery to get data below:

```
1. Address: 6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A
2. City: Falls Church
3. State: VA
4. ZIP: 22041
```

Thanks!

Comment: Provide more input examples.

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about inner text only.

Comment: Strip all the tags out first (use regex or not), then parse the address.

Comment: Be more clear about what your string is. Your snippet includes some html... and parsing html with regex is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
(.*)\n(.*?),\s([A-Z]{2})\s(\d{5})
```

Javascript:

```js
var str = $("address").text()
var extract = str.match(/(.*)\n(.*?),\s([A-Z]{2})\s(\d{5})/);

var address = extract[1];
var city = extract[2];
var state = extract[3];
var zip = extract[4];

console.log(address) // 6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A
console.log(city)    // Falls Church
console.log(state)   // VA
console.log(zip)     // 22041
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<address>
6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A<br>
Falls Church, VA 22041-2102
</address>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcr5gpLx/)

Comment: @Naramsim jquery doesn't have any methods that would assist with this task.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and copy the fiddle here

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, wasn't aware how to get that. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Most pragmatic, assuming no other commas in the state/zip - much easier to read and more maintainable than a oneliner regexp

jQuery is only used to get and set the HTML - innerHTML can be used to not need jQuery at all

```js
$(function() {
  var addr = $("address").html(),
    parts1 = addr.replace(/\s+/g, " ").split(/<br>/i),
    parts2 = parts1[1].split(","),
    parts3 = parts2[1].trim().split(" "),

    address = parts1[0].trim(),
    city = parts2[0].trim(),
    state = parts3[0].trim(),
    zip = parts3[1].trim(); // spirit on - if you need first part only 
  $("ol").after("<ol><li>Address: "+address+
     "</li><li>City: "+city+
     "</li><li>State: "+state+
     "</li><li>Zip: "+zip+"</li>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<address>
       6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A<br>
       Falls Church, VA 22041-2102
    </address>

<ol>
  <li>Address: 6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A</li>
  <li>City: Falls Church</li>
  <li>State: VA</li>
  <li>ZIP: 22041-2102</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    console.log(`<address>
           6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A<br>
           Falls Church, VA 22041-2102
        </address>`.match(/(\d+.*)<br>\n\t?(.*), (\w+) ([\d-]+)/))
```

No jQuery needed

Comment: A lot of unnecessary spaces

Comment: use .trim() please

Comment: *I* did use trim

Answer (score 0):

```
<address>[^\d]*(\d{1,4}[^<,]*)(?:<br\/?>|,)\s*([^,]*),\s*([A-Z]{2})\s*(\d{3,5})[^<]*<\/address>
```

Breakdown

```
<address> = start anchor
[^\d]* = eat all non digits
(\d{1,4}[^<,]*) Capture address
(?:<br\/?>|,)\s* eat to a <br> or comma
([^,]*) = Capture city
([A-Z]{2}) = capture state code
(\d{3,5}) = capture zip
[^<]* = eat rest too anchor
<\/address> = end anchor
```

```js
var str = "<address>\
   6231 Leesburg Pike Ste 100A<br>\
   Falls Church, VA 22041-2102\
</address>";
console.log(str.match(/<address>[^\d]*(\d{1,4}[^<,]*)(?:<br\/?>|,)\s*([^,]*),\s*([A-Z]{2})\s*(\d{3,5})[^<]*<\/address>/))
```

Comment: I find this unreadable and nearly impossible to modify if something changes

Comment: I was thinking that about all of the answers.

Comment: @mplungjan ... that is regex for you, the more readable it is, the less reliable it is. But the groups are all small though so if you know regex, you can just read left to right. (and that is why I gave a breakdown of each step)

Comment: _'the more readable it is, the less reliable it is'_ - That is so not true!

Comment: @degant Regex is about explicitly stating what you do AND don't want. The less assumptions you can make about your input, the more you need to say to properly separate ALL the good and bad cases. I just mean to say regex complexity grows exponentially with problem complexity. (The only time regex is readable to non-regex lovers is when there are almost no variable conditions)